# Why is my SVG path bigger than my SVG viewport?

Tags: html, svg, path, height

I just started learning SVG and I ran upon something that seems pretty odd...

I have an SVG with a height and width of 25px. So it means that the viewport has a width of 25px and a height of 25px. When I inspect it using the chrome dev tools I get this:

[image]

But when I inspect the path that is inside of the SVG that has a width and height of 25px, I get this:

[image]

Wait, what? The path has a width of 25px and a height of 19px and it shows the path as if it was bigger than the SVG viewport... but why?

How is the path bigger than the actual SVG viewport?

How does it say that the path is 25px by 19px but when inspected with the dev tools you can see that the path element is way bigger...

What causes this to happen?

Comment: Not very sure I understand you. Does the path have a width and a height attributes? The path's width and height is the path's bounding box width and height. You can get the bounding box of an svg element using the method getBBox()

Comment: No the path doesn't have a width and height assigned to it . The svg element does.